# Reasons For Using Basic Authentication vs. Digest Authentication vs. Windows Authentication

Tags: security, windows-authentication, basic-authentication, digest-authentication

I am studying for the Microsoft 70-486 exam and part of the exam covers the different types of challenge-response authentication protocols. The study guide that I am reading describes basic authentication which is in plain text, digest authentication which is hashed and windows authentication which uses a stronger encryption method. I am wondering if there is more to the story because this is a book written for a Microsoft exam. Is there a reason to ever use basic or digest authentication instead of windows authentication?

Comment: Not clear whether you ask on how to pick one from the three or rather you wonder why would anyone pick anyone of these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you'll use Windows auth on your intranet. Basic is less tied to a Windows domain client and server, so *maybe* it'll be more usable on the internet. Of course, you **must use SSL** with Basic (**MUST!**).

Also, Windows Authentication isn't fully supported on most non-windows clients. Even if some aspect of Windows Authentication works (NTLM) you'll still see a login box (no automatic login which is a big pro for Windows Auth). It does work on a *few* other platforms that understand a windows domain like Safari on a Mac and Windows phone.

If credentials need to be delegated from the web server to another server (like a SQL Server), I've found that you may run into problems for clients using NTLM (Basic or Negotiate/Kerberos often delegates easier). I've been told if my servers were configured for **constrained** delegation NTLM would work, but that's not been my experience.

EDIT: I've never used digest.

Comment: Thanks for your response, after doing some additional reading it appears that both basic and digest authentication use HTTP headers to pass information, while windows authentication with Kerberos uses UDP to pass information over a different port. That gives me some intuition into why basic and digest would be more fully supported. I am still doing some hunting on how the client exchanges NTLM.

Comment: Headers are passed back and forth in all these schemes. The client and server with kerberos still pass headers - it looks almost the same as NTLM or basic from an HTTP view of things. The UDP stuff is between the server and a domain controller.

Comment: windows auth does not work outside your windows based intranet. While Digest seems to be better than Basic auth because the password can not be extracted, it has the disadvantage that the password must be stored in cleartext (or something similar) on the server so that the digest can be verified.